# IntellijIDEA не компилирует задачи из плагина JavaRushHomeWork

Tags: компиляция, intellij-idea

Выдает ошибку:

> Information:Using javac 1.7.0_80 to compile java sources
>   Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'JavaRushHomeWork'
>   Information:25.09.15 19:49 - Compilation completed with 4 errors and 0 warnings in 1s 23ms
>   C:\Users\1\Desktop\javas\JavaRushHomeWork\src\com\javarush\test\level06\lesson11\bonus01\Solution.java
>   Error:(10, 51) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class IOException
>     location: class com.javarush.test.level06.lesson11.bonus01.Solution
>   Error:(12, 9) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class BufferedReader
>     location: class com.javarush.test.level06.lesson11.bonus01.Solution
>   Error:(12, 38) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class BufferedReader
>     location: class com.javarush.test.level06.lesson11.bonus01.Solution
>   Error:(12, 57) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class InputStreamReader
>     location: class com.javarush.test.level06.lesson11.bonus01.Solution

Раньше все было ОК, а потом вдруг перестала видеть классы, что-ли?
Уже все переставил и обновил - все равно не находит чего-то.

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно нажать `Alt+Enter` на соответствующем `symbol`.
http://help.javarush.ru/questions/25615/javarushhomework

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).